# Separate comma values of each rows in PLSQL Oracle 11g version

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have an example table below and I'm looking for a way to separate values in each row on the table. I'm using oracle 11g, I've seen solutions(Lateral() pl/sql) but it's only compatible with a higher version (12g above).

| Id | value-comma |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 'a,b,c' |
| 20 | 'd,e,f' |
| 30 | 'g,h,i' |

Output:

| Id | value-comma |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 'a' |
| 10 | 'b' |
| 10 | 'c' |
| 20 | 'd' |
| 20 | 'e' |
| 20 | 'f' |
| 30 | 'g' |
| 30 | 'h' |
| 30 | 'i' |

Comment: You stopped your research too soon. There are at least 100 questions like yours for Oracle 11 and lower just on this site.

Comment: @mathguy thanks, I should have research more.